# Populating select menu in user registeration form using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to Laravel and I'm sure it is a rooky mistake, but I need all the help I can get. I wanted to add a new dropdown field with a list of countries to a registration form which will be populated form a database. i've tried to add the filed as below but i keep getting `$countries is undefined`.

Here is the registration blade:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('country') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="" id="country_id" required>
                        @foreach($countries as $id => $entry)
                            <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('country_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $entry }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @if($errors->has('country'))
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $errors->first('country') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
            </div>
```

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'         => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email'        => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password'     => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'phone'        => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:15'],
            'countries'    => ['required'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name'     => $data['name'],
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'countries'    => $data['country_id'],
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use \DateTimeInterface;
use App\Notifications\VerifyUserNotification;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'email_verified_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'email_verified_at',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'phone',
        'country_id',
        'specialty_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        self::created(function (User $user) {
            $registrationRole = config('panel.registration_default_role');
            if (!$user->roles()->get()->contains($registrationRole)) {
                $user->roles()->attach($registrationRole);
            }
        });
    }

    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->roles()->where('id', 1)->exists();
    }

    public function getEmailVerifiedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->format(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format')) : null;
    }

    public function setEmailVerifiedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['email_verified_at'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = app('hash')->needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;
        }
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
    }

    public function specialty()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Specialty::class, 'specialty_id');
    }

    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below method in `RegisterController`.I hope you have country list in database so

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $countries=Country::pluck('country_name','id');
    return view('auth.register',compact('countries'));
}
```

Comment: I get the below error:
```
Error
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Country" not found
```

And yes i have the list in my database.

Comment: @Richu import Country so use App\Models\Country;

Comment: also you can do $countries=\App\Models\Country::pluck('country_name','id');